# Python: append to an array of empty lists

Tags: python

How to declare an array of empty lists to be appended later on?

I have a file which contain user-movie data like this: **UserID::MovieID::Rating::Time** but the amount of entries for each UserIDs may differ. (Ex: UserID=1 may have 2 entries and UserID=2 may have 5 entries.)

**1::1193::5::978300760**
**1::661::3::978302109**
**...**
**2418::3408::4::978300275**
**2418::2355::5::978824291**

For each UserID, declare an empty list to contain the Rating(MovieIDs) > 3

```
num_user_id = 2418
user_adj_list = [None]*num_user_id

path = "/home/Desktop/ml-1m/ratings.dat"
source_file = open(path)

# line = UserID::MovieID::Rating::Timestamp
for line in source_file:
        user_id, movie_id, rating, time_stamp = line.split("::")
        if int(rating) > 3:
                user_adj_list[int(user_id)-1].append(int(movie_id))
```

I tried `[[] in range(num_user_id)]` as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not use a dict with the userId as key?

Comment: Could you expand on *"it didn't work"*? I think you meant `[[] for _ in range(...)]`.

Comment: I had "user_adj_list = [[] in range(num_user_id)]", but error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'append' was thrown

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `dict` like below.

```
num_user_id = 2418
user_adj_list = [None]*num_user_id


path = "/home/Desktop/ml-1m/ratings.dat"
source_file = open(path)


#       line = UserID::MovieID::Rating::Timestauser_adj_list
user_adj_list = dict()
for line in source_file:
        user_id, movie_id, rating, time_stauser_adj_list = line.split("::")
        if user_id not in user_adj_list:
            user_adj_list[user_id] = []
        if int(rating) > 3:
                user_adj_list[int(user_id)-1].append(int(movie_id))
```